# Odoo 9 domain www

Tags: nginx, odoo

I have several sites on odoo. If i enter name of database like mydatabase.com everything is fine. But if i enter www.mydatabase.com it redirects me on database selector. How can i escape such problem ?
My nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name .local;

        proxy_buffers 16 64k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        location /longpolling {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
        }
}
```

Odoo server cfg:

```
[options]
dbfilter = ^%h$
db_template = template1
db_host = False
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = False
db_port = False
auto_reload = False
csv_internal_sep = ,
debug_mode = False
demo = {}
email_from = False
import_partial =
limit_memory_hard = 1205306368
limit_memory_soft = 1005306368
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
list_db = True
login_message = False
logrotate = True
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
netrpc = False
netrpc_interface =
netrpc_port = 8070
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = None
pidfile = False
proxy_mode = False
reportgz = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have two separate server headers like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://mydatabase.com$request_uri;

}


server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name mydatabase.com;

        proxy_buffers 16 64k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        location /longpolling {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
        }

}
```

The first one just listens for requests with www and redirects to the second one, which handles proxies the request to odoo

There are other **"shorter"** ways of doing this but this is the most straight-forward way IMO